# iron router add parameter to string as well as add a query

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, url-routing, iron-router

Just started playing around with meteor and I'm trying to use `iron-router` for the routing. Here is my **data structure**:

```
team
  _id
  name
  tags:[{name,counter}]
```

And here is the linking I'm trying to use in the **template**

```
{{#each team.tags}}
   <a href="{{ pathFor 'team' _id:parent._id query...? }}">#{{this.name}} <span class="count-list">{{this.counter}}</span></a> 
{{/each}}
```

And my **router** has:

```
route('/team/:_id')  // And I get the search through the GET property... this.params.query
```

So:

1. How do I get the parent team _id in the template?
2. How can I pass the _id and the search parameter in the `pathFor`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `../` to step back to the parent scope, which in this case appears to be `teams`

```
{{#each team.tags}}
   <a href="{{pathFor 'team' _id=../_id query='queryString'}}">#{{this.name}} <span class="count-list">{{this.counter}}</span></a> 
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks. So that's passing the team _id, what about passing a search query?

Comment: Haven't had time to test it myself just yet. Looks right, I remember something about the ..